# When to use char array instead of strings in c++?

Tags: c++, stdstring, string-literals

How do we differentiate char arrays and string in c++?
Is there anything char arrays do better than std::string ?

Comment: To use c++ STL you should use string, Otherwise it is not needed for simple operation.

Comment: @starboy_jb Standard algorithms work equally well with char arrays.

Comment: Come on, this does not have to be opinion-based. E.g. `std::string` cannot be used in `constexpr` context before C++20, so I still prefer `const char[]` for global constants unless I need to do some string operations with them.

Comment: A typical use case is when you want to reuse old code/library, that you wrote decades ago, and don't want to rewrite!

Comment: @Quimby `constexpr` `string_view`s should also work. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That is true, thanks, perhaps I should start using that instead.

Comment: @Quimby You should write it as an answer

Answer (score 4):

One reason (which I personally don't think is a very good one) to use char arrays is the use case when you want your code to compile with both a C compiler and a C++ compiler.

Comment: @bruno I was debating about that with myself, but I think it is a valid answer. However rare and misused this use case may be, it is a use case. And it is something that char arrays can do and std::string cannot, which is exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: if the goal is to also compile in C there is no choice so no question too ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> How do we differentiate char arrays and string in c++?

You don't, string literals are by definition null-terminated char arrays. Since arrays decay into pointers the first chance they get, `const char*` is (still) often a synonym for string.

If you are asking about when you should write `new char[n]`, the answer is never. If anything, it should be `std::make_unique<char[]>(n);` and unless you are writing your own version of `std::string`, use the standard one. If you need a buffer, use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

There are some advantages of `const char[]` constants over `const std::string` but they are being "solved" by the new C++ Standards:

1. Before C++20, `std::string` could not be used in `constexpr` context. So, I still prefer declaring global string constants with `constexpr const char[]` if all I do is just passing them to some function. As @HolyBlackCat mentioned in the comments, C++17 `std::string_view` makes this use-case obsolote too, especially with the new `sv` literal:

   ```cpp
   #include <string_view>
   using namespace std::literals;
   //Compile-time string_view
   constexpr auto str = "hello"sv;
   ```
2. `const char*` is somewhat more universal. You can pass it to a function accepting `const char*`, `std::string`, or `std::string_view`. The reverse requires `std::string::c_str()` and it is not possible to so without copying the `std::string_view`.
3. There is no dynamic allocation involved. Although `std::string` might employ SSO, it is not guaranteed. This might be relevant for very small systems where the heap is precious and the program flash memory is more accomodating and contains the literal anyway.
4. Interacting with old libraries. But even then, `std::string` is null-terminated too.

Overall, my recommendation would be to use `std::string_view` every chance you get - for any non-owning string, including holding string literals. Most importantly, it should replace `const char*` and `const std::string&` function parameters. If you want to own a string, use `std::string`.

Comment: This suggested use of `string_view` has a problem: if you then need to call a function that expects a read-only null-terminated string (e.g. third-party library), you have to copy the whole viewed string to add the terminator, even though the source for the string-view already had it. Which is a waste of time and resources.

Comment: @M.M Yes, that is correct, my advice was aimed at new code without old dependencies. It's a tradeoff, `std::string_view` can do non-suffix-based substrings without copy, which ordinary read-only null-terminated string cannot.